# SQL Server OPENQUERY as a Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'd like to use linked server as a variable in an `OPENQUERY`. How do I make it work?

```
SET @LinkedServer = 'MyLinkedServer';

INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (Product, Name, State)
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENQUERY ('+@LinkedServer+', 'SELECT Product, Name, ''IL'' FROM DBNAME.TABLE_1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kamran, thanks for your information.

I have worked out a solution as followed:

SET @TSQL = N'INSERT INTO TABLE_2
(Product, Name, State)
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY('+@linkedServer+','SELECT Product, Name, ''''IL'''' FROM DBNAME.TABLE_1);'

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (answer sourced from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314520)):

```
DECLARE @OPENQUERY nvarchar(4000), @TSQL nvarchar(4000), @LinkedServer nvarchar(4000)
SET @LinkedServer = 'MyLinkedServer'
SET @OPENQUERY = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY('+ @LinkedServer + ','''
SET @TSQL = 'SELECT Product, Name, ''IL'' FROM DBNAME.TABLE_1'')' +
INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (Product, Name, State)
EXEC (@OPENQUERY+@TSQL)
```